# How to call native share via option using Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to implement share via option in PhoneGap. I'm unable to find any working plugin. I have used [SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin), but got lots of errors while copying Java file in src.

How to call native share option? Does anybody know of a working plugin?

Comment: socialsharing plugin does work.

Comment: DO you have any sample app.I am using phonegap 2.9.0 version

Comment: Am searching lot for this problem.cant able to implement it

Comment: Do you implemented successfully.Its working fine for you.which version you are using.->Marcin Mikolajczyk

Comment: I dont have access to my code now. I wrote it for 2.9 version also, it just worked, follow docs.

Comment: can you send the link of plugin you used

Comment: same link you posted in question

Comment: hi i have implemented it.there are no errors in it.I have given my index.html file like this                                          <html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="SocialSharing.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
   <button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message only')">message only</button>
    </body>
</html> but nothing happens on tap button.Do you faced any problem like this.

Comment: while implementing .java file,I have faced some errors.         import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult; then i changed cordova.api.PluginResult instead of cordova.PluginResult then errors was cleared.But nothing is working on click button.

Comment: I didnt. does the console say anything?

Comment: did you use this https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/tree/phonegap-2.x/ ? (this is for versions less than 3)

Comment: ya i have did that too.on click button nothing happens in that plugin too.In console to no errors

Comment: are you testing on real device or emulator?